# Insertar enlace dentro de un botón

Tags: html, css, css3

Tengo un sitio en el cual utilizo botones para identificar una ciudad. Cuando se hace click en cada ciudad se desplega la una imagen que indica el título un texto que dice “mas info”.

El problema es que quiero agregar una etiqueta `a` dentro del botón y cuando el usuario hace click no se desplega, sino que lo envía al sitio directamente. También traté de hacerlo dentro del `div` pero sigo con el mismo problema.

¿Cómo puedo insertar un enlace dentro de un botón sin que afecte la animación?

```css
body {font-family: Arial, sans-serif;}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
div {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


h2 {
  font-size: 24pt;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

p {
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 12pt;
}

.centered-y {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.distribution-map {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.distribution-map>img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.distribution-map .map-point {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s ease-in-out, transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
  background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
  border: 3px solid #7fcff7;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 0;
}

.distribution-map .map-point::before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background:white;
  top: 50%;
  left:  50%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active::before,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus::before {
  display: none;
}

.distribution-map .map-point .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: overlay;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 172px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.25s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.25 ease-in-out, transform 0.25s;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active .content,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0s, 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:hover,
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:hover,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:active {
  color: #afe1fa;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
div {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


h2 {
  font-size: 24pt;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

p {
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 12pt;
}

.centered-y {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.distribution-map {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.distribution-map>img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.distribution-map .map-point {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s ease-in-out, transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
  background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
  border: 3px solid #7fcff7;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 0;
}

.distribution-map .map-point::before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background:white;
  top: 50%;
  left:  50%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active::before,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus::before {
  display: none;
}

.distribution-map .map-point .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: overlay;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 375px;
  height: 172px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.25s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.25 ease-in-out, transform 0.25s;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active .content,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0s, 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:hover,
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:hover,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:active {
  color: #afe1fa;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="distribution-map">
<img src="http://allonCiudad.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/mapafondo.png">

<button class="map-point" style="top:30%;left:59%">
<div class="content" style="background-image: url('constitucion.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: contain;">
</div>
</button>

<button class="map-point" style="top:16%;left:65%">
<div class="content" style="background-image: url('itati.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: contain;">
</button>

<button class="map-point" style="top:19%;left:67%">
<div class="content" style="background-image: url('ibera.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: contain;">
</button>

<button class="map-point" style="top:46%;left:29%">
<div class="content" style="background-image: url('patagonia.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: contain;">
</div>
</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Este HTML es inválido: el elemento `div` no está permitido como hijo de `button`. Más en general, los elemento de tipo en línea (_inline elements_), no pueden contener elementos de tipo bloque (_block elements_). Deberias usar otro elemento en lugar de `button`, en este caso sugiero `a`. Por favor leer: https://guiadev.com/validar-el-codigo-html-y-css/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hola puedes apoyarte de jquery para hacer lo que necesitas

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
     //aqui agregar tu contenido al div que muestra
     $('.content').append($('<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">Detalle</a>'));
});
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, sans-serif; background:black;}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
div {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


h2 {
  font-size: 24pt;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

p {
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 12pt;
}

.centered-y {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.distribution-map {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.distribution-map>img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.distribution-map .map-point {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s ease-in-out, transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
  background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
  border: 3px solid #7fcff7;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 0;
}

.distribution-map .map-point::before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background:white;
  top: 50%;
  left:  50%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active::before,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus::before {
  display: none;
}

.distribution-map .map-point .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: overlay;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 172px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.25s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.25 ease-in-out, transform 0.25s;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active .content,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0s, 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:hover,
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:hover,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:active {
  color: #afe1fa;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
div {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


h2 {
  font-size: 24pt;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

p {
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 12pt;
}

.centered-y {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.distribution-map {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.distribution-map>img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.distribution-map .map-point {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s ease-in-out, transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
  background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
  border: 3px solid #7fcff7;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 0;
}

.distribution-map .map-point::before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background:white;
  top: 50%;
  left:  50%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active::before,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus::before {
  display: none;
}

.distribution-map .map-point .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: overlay;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 375px;
  height: 172px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.25s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.25 ease-in-out, transform 0.25s;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active .content,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0s, 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:hover,
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:hover,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:active {
  color: #afe1fa;
}
}
```

```html
<br><br><br>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="distribution-map">
<img src="http://allonCiudad.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/mapafondo.png">

<button class="map-point" style="top:30%;left:59%">
<div class="content" style="background-image: url('constitucion.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: contain;">
</div>
</button>

<button class="map-point" style="top:16%;left:65%">
<div class="content" style="background-image: url('itati.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: contain;">
</button>

<button class="map-point" style="top:19%;left:67%">
<div class="content" style="background-image: url('ibera.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: contain;">
</button>

<button class="map-point" style="top:46%;left:29%">
<div class="content" style="background-image: url('patagonia.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: contain;">
</div>
</button>

</div>
```

- En este caso lo estoy haciendo en la carga del documento
- Si quieres diferentes enlaces para cada uno deberas crear ids para cada div

Comment: Gracias Carlos, estoy tratando de pasarlo a javascript porque cada boton tiene un link distinto. Estoy tratando de hacer esto: `function content() {
 $('#ibera').append($('<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">Detalle</a>'));
}` para usar desde un `id`, pero no me funciona

Comment: no esta de mas preguntar pero, le agregaste la etiqueta id en el div ?

Comment: Eso lo hice, pero al tratar de pasarlo a javascript no funciona: este es el div: `<div class="content" id="ibera"` y este es el script: `function content() {
 $('#ibera').append($('<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/"></a>'));
}`